# 'sample.exe' not recognised as internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe, environment-variables, path

Under Environment Variables, I set the path to sample.exe.

I appended the System variable PATH with,

C:\Program Files(x86)\Sample

The sample.exe is in the Sample folder.

Still, I get the above error message. Where did I go wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Need more information what was the value you appended to the PATH Environment variable ? Did you close and open a new cmd window ? If not, do that first.

Comment: Yes. I did close and tried in a newly opened cmd window. It didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is just a typographical error but you have a quotation mark at the end of your path and none at the beginning.

You are also missing a space in the path Program Files**_**(x86).

Comment: I was missing a space in Program Files<space>(x86). Thank you @qasdfdsaq

Answer (score 0):

In all MS-DOS style related paths and commands you should use `""`, because otherwise special characters including spaces will not be correctly interpreted.

So instead of something like

C:\Program files

always use

"C:\Program files".